# Two Factories. One should know when there is a change in Other

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-service, angularjs-factory

Before i state my question, i may be completely wrong with how i am using factories in my use case. Happy to know better alternatives.

So, I have two Factories.

`Factory1` takes care of hitting the server, getting and storing that data.

`Factory2` does not make any REST Calls. But stores a set of data that would be useful while making REST calls.

Simple question would be, why not Factory1 store that data instead of Factory2. **The motive behind Factory2 is that this data would be used by lot of other factories/controllers. So, to remove redundancy this looks a better option.**

For now,
When a REST call is to be made from Factory1, i can simply do Factory2.getData and then use it. But my use-case is bit more complex. **I need Factory1 to fire calls whenever there is a change in Factory2.getData().** We would use $scope normally in case of controllers etc. But how to achieve the same thing here ?

**Basically, How to do we know in Factory1 when there is a change in Factory2's data ?**

Code:

```
servicesModule.factory('Factory2', function() {

 var fObj = {},
    filters;

fObj.setFilters = function(fs) {
    filters = fs;
};

fObj.getFilters = function() {
    return filters;
};

return fObj;
});

servicesModule.factory('Factory1', ['$http', '$q', 'Factory2', function($http, $q, Factory2) {
            var fObj = {},
            data;
            fObj.fetchData = function(params) {
                var filters = Factory2.getFilters(); 
                // REST call here and set data to result
            }
            fObj.getData = function(){
                    return data;
            }
    }]);
```

Comment: use `$rootScope.$broadcast`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, a bit of digging pointed in the direction of $rootScope.

```
servicesModule.factory('Factory2', ['$rootScope', function($rootScope) {

     var fObj = {},
        filters;

    fObj.setFilters = function(fs) {
        filters = fs;
        $rootScope.$emit("FiltersUpdated", fs);
    };

    fObj.getFilters = function() {
        return filters;
    };

    return fObj;
}]);

servicesModule.factory('Factory1', ['$http', '$q', 'Factory2', '$rootScope', function($http, $q, Factory2, $rootScope) {
        var fObj = {},
        data;

        $rootScope.$on('FiltersUpdated', function(event, data) {
            fObj.fetchData();
        })

        fObj.fetchData = function(params) {
            var filters = Factory2.getFilters(); 
            // REST call here and set data to result
        }
        fObj.getData = function(){
                return data;
        }
}]);
```

I would still love to hear others' opinions.